# Why we call the identity map the inclusion?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

In the following picture :

[image]

The hint beside question 2(a) said that we will use $g$ as the inclusion map, while in the following picture the solution is given by considering $g$
  the identity map.

[image]

What is the relation between the identity map and inclusion map?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For example, the map $f:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}\;$defined by
$$f(n) = n,\;\text{for all}\;n \in \mathbb{Z}$$
is an inclusion map, but is not an identity map.

For one thing, it's not surjective.

More importantly, the domain and codomain are not the same.

An identity map is a function from a set $A\;$to itself which fixes every element of $A$.

An inclusion map is a function from a set $A\;$to a set $B,\;$where $A \subseteq B,\;$which fixes every element of $A$.

Comment: but in the above answer to the question, why the author used identity map instead of the inclusion map, could you explain this for me please?

Comment: For 2(a), the domain of the map $g$ is $D=\text{ker}(f)$, which need not be all of $A$, whereas the codomain is $A$. So $g$ can be an inclusion map, but doesn't qualify as an identity map.

Comment: Also, when you say that in the solution, the author used "identity map", I don't see the word "identity" anywhere in that picture.

Answer (score 1):

The identity map and the inclusion map are both injective. If $A\subseteq B$, we can define the inclusion map $i:A\longrightarrow B$ from a set $A$ to a set $B$ as follows:
$$i(x)=x,\ \forall x\in A$$
this is a generalization of the identity map which correspond to the case $A=B$. Both are injective maps.

In your text, the inclusion is present because $D=\mathrm{ker}(f)\subseteq A$. So, you can consider an monomorphism (that is, injective homomorphism) given by the inclusion map:

$$g:D\longrightarrow A$$

and this defined by:

$$g(x)=x,\ \forall\, x\in D.$$

I call $g$ the inclusion map of $D$ in $A$ like your text.

Comment: Can they both be used interchangeably as seen in the question above?

Comment: They are not the same, the idenity map is an special case of the inclusion $A\subseteq A$.